# Объединить несколько PDF в один

Tags: python, pdf

Объединить несколько PDF в один,, их количество не постоянное, так же чаще всего находятся в разных директориях

Comment: Каков Ваш алгоритм действий? Какими библиотеками пользовались, чтобы решить данную задачу? Где Ваш код? Отредактируйте вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью модуля [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/):

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

merger = PdfFileMerger()
merger.append('1.pdf')
merger.append('2.pdf')
merger.write('result.pdf')
merger.close()
```

Тест https://repl.it/repls/SeparateModernPostscript

Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3444645/13970074)

Comment: Метод рабочий , но не подходит под мои задачи , прошу прощения сам не правильно задал вопрос

Comment: @KoTAK не надо изменять вопрос так, чтобы он инвалидировал текущие ответы. Задайте новый вопрос, а этот откатите обратно